# find Item wise max sales on which month in python series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

```
s1=pd.Series([100,200,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s2=pd.Series([102,205,333,433,502],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s3=pd.Series([101,2200,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s4=pd.Series([102,2200,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s5=pd.Series([104,2300,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s6=pd.Series([105,2700,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s7=pd.Series([105,2800,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s8=pd.Series([306,2900,3900,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s9=pd.Series([400,2090,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s10=pd.Series([500,2900,3090,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s11=pd.Series([600,2090,3090,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
s12=pd.Series([1000,200,300,400,500],index=['item1','item2','item3','item4','item5'])
```

these are sales data of item1, item2, item3, item4 and item5 for each month wise means s1 data is for month 1, s2 data is for month 2 so on. i need to find in which month item1 sold max , then item2, item3, item4, item5  through python programming.

i was trying like this , just checking if i am getting the values or not

```
def fn():
    for i in range(12):
        print(i)
print("Maximum Sales for Individual Items")
for i in s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12:
    for j in range(5):
        x=i[j]
        fn(x)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: should i add that too?

Answer (score 3):

Organize this into a single DataFrame, where the row Index is the item and the column Index indicates the month. Then you can use `.idxmax(axis=1)` to get the month of maximum sales per item.

```
df = pd.concat([s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12], keys=range(1,13), axis=1)
df.idxmax(1)

#item1    12
#item2     8
#item3     8
#item4     2
#item5     2
#dtype: int64
```

If you want to know all months in the case of ties, find the `max` per item and use `where` + `stack` to keep only values that equal that max. This also retains the maximum value if that's important.

```
df.where(df.eq(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)).stack()

#item1  12    1000.0
#item2  8     2900.0
#       10    2900.0
#item3  8     3900.0
#item4  2      433.0
#item5  2      502.0
#dtype: float64
```

Comment: hello sir, is it possible to do it without making dataframe ?

Comment: @SETSrkians yes though it's much more complicated because now we have to deal with checking multiple objects for each item. Ideally you would start from the DataFrame instead of all of these different Series, as you generally don't want all of these different variables just floating around and it's best to have a single container, be that a dict, or in this case the DataFrame. Is it really necessary to not have the DataFrame?